# Unable to strncpy into class member string (array of char) from member function

Tags: c++

While trying to copy a string formatted with a vsnprintf, into a class member variable, with strncpy, the destination string is not written, although the return from strncpy which is a pointer to the destination string shows that it is written.

Traced with dbx.

```
void Elf::errstr(const char *fmt, ...){
    va_list arg;
    char buf[ERRMAX+1];

    va_start(arg, fmt);
    vsnprintf(buf, ERRMAX, fmt, arg);
    va_end(arg);
    char *s = strncpy(errbuf, buf, ERRMAX);
}
```

This routine is part of a large 'Elf' class implementing methods for accessing elf files. The idea is that when an error occurs somewhere in a class member function, a string 'errbuf' is set to the error message. This can then be accessed with Elf::error() which simply returns this string. If I check 'errbuf' with the debugger after the call, it shows a null string, while 's' points to the string copied from 'buf'. When I extracted this code into a much simpler example it works, so I am very puzzled as to what is going on.

Comment: Try printing out the address of the array in both cases (e.g. `printf("%p\n", errbuf);` -- perhaps there are two different variables named `errbuf` at play here?

Comment: Thank you. There is indeed a problem with multiply defined 'errbuf'. I don't know how this has happened but when I print the address of errbuf as you suggested, in the constructor, in the call to open and the call to errstr, it is the same address, but the final 'error' routine reveals a different address.

Comment: @N.Hunt Curious as to why you're using very `C`-ish code for a C++ class / application.  Also, what exactly is `errbuf`?  Is it a global variable?  If so, why is it global, and not encapsulated in the `Elf` class?

Comment: I'm basically a C programmer, but I am 'borrowing' a nice library of C code and turning into C++ to work with a debugger ('pi' from Eigth Edition Unix). There is a dwarf module as well. 'errbut' isn't global per se, it is simply a char array in the class as you mention it should be. It was inaccurate to say global.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but since `vsnprintf` itself limits the size of the output, there's no reason for that separate buffer and that call to `strncpy`. Just format the string directly into `errbuf`. Further, as used here, `strncpy` just replaces one bug with another. Read about what it does when the text is too long. `strncpy` is not a "safe" replacement for `strcpy` for any reasonable definition of "safe".

Comment: My gut instinct is that either you are calling `errstr()` on an invalid `Elf` object, or its `errbuf` member is a `char*` pointer that is not pointing where you are expecting, such as if the `Elf` has been copied and is not implementing the "Rule of 3/5/0" correctly. Hard to say for sure without seeing a [mcve].

Comment: The problem was caused by slipshod cut and paste of rules in the Makefile, whereby I ended up linking in a library that wasn't needed but it was interfering somehow. I couldn't work out how however. Your advice about writing straight into errbuf from vsnprintf is welcome. I will amend the code. I am also interested in how you might write this same code in a more C++ fashion. I write like this because that's partly because I am working from C code and also, 'pi' was written in the days of 'cfront' (1985, Tom Cargill) and the code is very much C with decorations.